# Issue while installing the VLC

Tags: 14.04, vlc

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvncclient0 (>= 0.9.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not installable
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not installable
 vlc-plugin-fluidsynth : Depends: fluid-soundfont-gm but it is not installable or
                                  musescore-soundfont-gm but it is not installable
                         Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libfluidsynth1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-jack : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-libde265 : Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-notify : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-samba : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-sdl : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-svg : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-zvbi : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libzvbi0 (>= 0.2.33) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` just to be safe. What's the output of `apt-cache policy vlc vlc-nox libvlccore8`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. After installing the Ubuntu 14.04, install the **Ubuntu Restricted Packages** from Ubuntu software center. Successful installation of this allow the VLC to install properly.

Regards,
Bainab